# Is it better to self-publish or get a real publisher for a 100page humor/comedy ebook?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, ebook

I plan on writing an ebook that's exactly 100 pages in length.
This book will be comedy, basically my humorous take on situations.

I think it's adequate as an ebook since ideally you'll read a page on your phone and have a good laugh.

Should I try to get a real publisher (which means getting a literary agent) for this ebook, or would it be better to self-publish since I have some specifics about how this book should be read.

Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I would think a self published book would be better in this situation.  The reviewers may or may not find your content to be of their taste since humor is highly subjective and you may end up getting turned down by a publisher.  I don't know much about writing comedy though and how that relates.  This is merely my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

There are four basic reasons to self publish:

1. The work is not good enough for a commercial publisher to accept.
2. You are not willing to put in the work to get it professionally published.
3. You are confident in your ability to market the book yourself and believe you will make more money publishing it yourself. (But read stuff like this first: https://janefriedman.com/self-publishing-debut-literary-novel/)
4. The book is so specialized that there is no commercial publisher who understands and serves that market.

A book of humorous observations clearly does not fall into the fourth category. Only you can answer whether it falls into the other three.